# How to bind an external port to an internal port?

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, port

I am trying to play a multiplayer game with a friend. The problem is that we both need to have the same ports set up to be able to connect to each other. typing `port` and `externalport` in the game console outputs the same thing for me: `31313`. When my friend does the same thing, typing `port` outputs to `31313` and `externalport` to `29765`.

How can I make the external port the same as the internal port ? My friend has a Tenda Router, if it helps.

Comment: are you on the same Internet connection? also, It doesn't really make sense that you need to be on the same port to connect. what makes you think you do?

Comment: I'm using SmartSteamEmulator. The forum says right there that the players need to use the same ports to be able to connect

Comment: and you guys are both on differant internet connections, right? external ports don't mean much if you are both on the same internal network. As for your port, that you can't specifiy it indicates to me that its using UPNP for opening ports on your router. you could port forward 31313 through your router.

Comment: I have port `31313 ` forwarded on my side, and we are using Tunngle to connect to each other. Tunngle's ports are forwarded as well on my side. He still can not connect to me. Firewall isn't an issue for either of us.